# Return a big object array from JNI?

Tags: java-native-interface, jnienv

According to the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#EnsureLocalCapacity)

> jint EnsureLocalCapacity(JNIEnv *env, jint capacity);
>
> Ensures that at least a given number of local references can be
>   created in the current thread. Returns 0 on success; otherwise returns
>   a negative number and throws an OutOfMemoryError.
>
> Before it enters a native method, the VM automatically ensures that at
>   least 16 local references can be created.
>
> For backward compatibility, the VM allocates local references beyond
>   the ensured capacity. (As a debugging support, the VM may give the
>   user warnings that too many local references are being created. In the
>   JDK, the programmer can supply the -verbose:jni command line option to
>   turn on these messages.) The VM calls FatalError if no more local
>   references can be created beyond the ensured capacity.

It seems there is some limitation for the number of Local Reference can be created.

And I have following code to return a big object array, which leads to a lot of Local Reference creation.  Does that mean this would reach the limitation easily?  -- the doc says 16 by default.

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT
jobjectArray JNICALL Java_MessageQueueInterop_receive(JNIEnv * env, jobject this_obj, jclass cls)
{
    int count = 99999;
    jobjectArray ret = env->NewObjectArray( count, cls, NULL);
    if( ret ){
        for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
            jobject obj = env->NewObject( cls, constructor);
            if( obj ){
            env->SetIntField( obj, fieldID1, 2);

            jstring str = env->NewStringUTF("XXX");
            if( str )
                env->SetObjectField( obj, fieldID2, str);

            env->SetObjectArrayElement( ret, i, obj);
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

How to extend the limitation?

Comment: *Of course* creating 100,000 objects will hit a 16-object limit, but I would first ask why you're writing this code in JNI at all. It's six lines of Java code.

Comment: The code above is not actual code.  The real code receives the data from boost shared memory queue and there will be a lot of elements arriving

Comment: fieldID1 is what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well 100,000 > 16 so you will definitely have trouble.

You could try a combination of [`PushLocalFrame()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#push_local_frame) and [`PopLocalFrame()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#pop_local_frame), as follows:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT
jobjectArray JNICALL Java_MessageQueueInterop_receive(JNIEnv * env, jobject this_obj, jclass cls)
{
    int count = 99999;
    jobjectArray ret = env->NewObjectArray( count, cls, NULL);
    if( ret ){
        for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
            PushLocalFrame(env, 1); // TODO error checking required here
            jobject obj = env->NewObject( cls, constructor);
            if( obj ){
                env->SetIntField( obj, fieldID1, 2);
                jstring str = env->NewStringUTF("XXX");
                if( str )
                    env->SetObjectField( obj, fieldID2, str);
            }
            obj = PopLocalFrame(env, obj);
            env->SetObjectArrayElement( ret, i, obj);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

E&OE. Might work, might not. [On second thoughts, probably not.]

It might be better to have the caller provide a `LinkedList` so you don't have to allocate this huge array, and maybe a calling loop so you only add one element from the native queue at a time inside the JNI, or else a callback into Java to allocate the object.

Comment: The `PopLocalFrame`  frees all the local references before returning?